# while loop throwing error javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using while loop to attach an event in element. However event is successfully added but the function also throw error on console. if I use pre-increment then its worked fine. I just want to know what is the problem with post increment. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r19r7djb/)

```
var elements= document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
i=0;

while(elements[i++]){
    if(elements[i].className=='c') {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
            alert(this.className)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `i++` in the loop header means that the value of `i` is **one greater** than it was when the test was made. You'll skip element 0 and try to process the element past the end of the list.

So when this runs:

```
while (elements[i++])
```

the element index that's *tested* will be 0 through the last element, the value of `i` after that point will be one more than that. That's because `i++` means "use the value of `i` but increment it afterwards".

When you used pre-increment (`++i`) it was *still* wrong, unless you initialized `i` to `-1`.

Really this is why we have the `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; elements[i]; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

That way the value of `i` remains the same from the loop test through the end of the loop body.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    i = 0;

while (elements[i]) {    
    if (elements[i].className == 'c') {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            alert(this.className)
        })
    }

    i++;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r19r7djb/3/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `++` operator. You should utilize aggregate operations instead. They are a useful abstraction layer against loops. They allow you think of iteration without concern for the intricacies of side-effecting operations like incrementing.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

function toArray(list) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(list);
}

toArray(elements).forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.className === 'c') {
        element.addEventListener('click', function () {
            alert(this.className);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: IE9+. If you require IE8 or lower support, you can use a library like Lodash (https://lodash.com/), which provides a `forEach` function, among other things.